# Implement postback call using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp.net MVC5 project.

I have this HTML row:

```
  <input id="setCulture" type="hidden" name="culture" value="" />
```

and this JQuery  row:

```
 $('#setCulture').parents("form").submit();
```

The jQuery implements postback event.

I need to implement postback call with pure JavaScript code.

What is appropriate code in pure JavaScript  for jQuery line above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `input` has a `form` property which points to the form the `input` belongs to:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("setCulture").form;
myForm.submit();
```

Comment: The `form` attribute of inputs was introduced with HTML5. Do you know if this JavaScript works in older browsers that do not support the `form` attribute?

Comment: @ChrisPratt  it does not for sure... i currently working on project for ie8. :( but i gess it works for OP

Comment: Well, it works for the bit of testing they may have done so far, at least. I don't know of any dev that actually works in IE7 or 8. They generally use Chrome or Firefox (which does support it) and then (hopefully) tests in other browsers they need to support. On the off-chance that the OP neglects to test in lesser browsers, you should call out the potential problem explicitly.

Comment: And, actually, I don't think this even works in IE10 or 11. I needed to use the form attribute for a submit button that was outside of a form, and I seem to remember having to add some custom JavaScript for IE to ensure that clicking it still submitted the form.